# PDO set variable vs while loops

Tags: php, pdo

So I've spent the past week studying PDO and writing new code for me to use for my normal copy and paste mentality of adding extra scripts to my PHP App. But one thing I have noticed with PDO is I get the same outcome with

```
$item = $db_conn->query("SELECT * FROM `Item` ORDER BY date DESC");
while($row = $item->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
     echo $row[1];
     echo $row[2];
}
```

As I do with

```
$item = $db_conn->query("SELECT * FROM `Item` ORDER BY date DESC");
$row = $item->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $row[1];
echo $row[2];
```

So the real question is if you don't need to use the while loop to bind the array() to $row why is it almost standard for me to see people wright their code using the while loop? Is there perhaps some reason I am not seeing? Because I have found the later code example to be quicker more often than having to debug a faulty loop.

Comment: Obviously, if you don't use `while` it will throw error if the data isn't fetched

Comment: Just a side note, single quoted strings don't interpolate variables.

Comment: @NadirSampaoli It was just a quick type up to get the point across. I wasn't thinking because you are right it would give me $row[1] instead of the desired information from the array.

Comment: @Muhammet Ha. I feel like an idiot. I've been pulling from an already populated database so I never really thought of that.

Comment: This is just a question thats been bugging me since it seems simpler to go that second route, but I still use it within an if loop to see if their is a record. In the event of no record it presents a link to add a record, otherwise it prints the array formated into an HTML table. I just thought perhaps people are over thinking the process. But Really it is I who over thought it. Thank you everyone for the great answers!

Comment: I'm unsure why I got the down vote. It seems to me to be a valid question. I am sorry I'm not a master programmer like the rest of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the `while` for multiple records, you probably get the same result because it is only one record returned in your query.